# VBA loop through range and output if complete range is empty

Tags: vba

I have searched a lot about my question but could not find the answer I need.

I have a table A1:DT97138. Within this table I want to check per row, starting from cell B2 to DT2 if all the cells in one row are empty. Then output "Empty" or "Not Empty" in the next cell, DU2. Then do the same for row 3, 4 etc to 97138 (and output the same results row per row in DU2, DU3 etc).

I found out how to do this for 1 specific row, as you can see below, but I cannot find out how to iterate trough the whole range, row by row.

```
Sub rowEmpty()

    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Range("B2:DT97138")

    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B2:DT2")) = 0 Then
        Cells(2, 125) = "Empty"
    Else
        Cells(2, 125) = "Not Empty"
    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are doing well. Just need to loop thru the range like this.

```
Sub rowEmpty()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Range("B2:DT97138")

    For Each r In rng.Rows
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(r) = 0 Then
            Cells(r.Row, 125) = "Empty"
        Else
            Cells(r.Row, 125) = "Not Empty"
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Enter your formula at once in the last column:

```
With Range("DU2:DU97138")
     .Formula = "=IF(COUNTA(B2:DT2)=0,""Empty"",""Not Empty"")"
     'then eventually convert it to constants
     .Value = .Value
End With
```

No loops, simpler, probably much faster :-)